# EF and LINQ querying by subcollection properties

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I'm trying to order a list of "parent" items based on a value in its sub-collection's sub-collection. Here's the specifics...

I have a Film entity (mapped to the Films table) that has a one-to-many collection of Release entities (mapped to the Releases table). Each Release has one or more ReleaseDate entities (mapped to the ReleaseDates table).

```
public class Film {
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public string Title {get;set;}
    /* ... more properties here ...*/
}

public class Release {
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public int FilmId {get;set;}
    public virtual Film Film {get;set;}
    public virtual ICollection<ReleaseDate> ReleaseDates { get; set; }
    /* ... more properties here ...*/
}

public class ReleaseDate {
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public DateTime Date {get;set;}
    public int ReleaseId {get;set;}
    public virtual Release Release {get;set;}
    /* ... more properties here ...*/
}
```

Now, I want to order the Films by the earliest release date, but obviously a film could have no releases, and a release could have no release dates (again, 1-* relationships). The SQL equivalent would be...

```
SELECT * /* or whatever columns...*/
FROM dbo.Films F
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.Releases R ON R.FilmId = F.Id
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.ReleaseDates RD ON RD.ReleaseId = R.Id
ORDER BY RD.[Date] ASC /* or DESC */
```

How can I go about doing this?

Comment: Perhaps if I simplify a bit it will help. Let's say there's no database/DbContext involved at this point. I just have an IQueryable collection of films at this point. Does that help or does that make the situation more difficult? I'm willing to refactor to simplify things if need be.

Answer (score 0):

```
var orderedFilms = Films.OrderBy(a=> a.Releases.Any() ?  
                                     a.Releases.Select(x=>x.ReleaseDates.Any() ?
                                                           x.ReleaseDates.Min(d=>d.Date).Date :
                                                             DateTime.Now).Min() : DateTime.Now);
```

Comment: `asc` is from Minimum to Maximum and `desc` would be Maximum to Minimum.  In other words, I believe you should change `Max` to `Min` if I'm not mistaken.  `I want to order the Films by the earliest release date`.

Comment: @ErikPhilips thanks, my English is not good enough, sometime I'm mixed up between latest and earliest.

Comment: Where does "Releases" come from? I don't have a separate collection of Releases, they are a sub collection of the Film entities. (i.e. Film.Releases), so I don't think I can take this approach. Also, there are navigation properties between Film and Releases, and Release and ReleaseDates, so I'd like to take advantage of those. I think your example assumes that I don't have navigation properties. (If that is possible and makes sense??).

Comment: @HenryC yes, your `Film` class doesn't have a `Releases`, I can see that in your post.

Comment: This gives me 3 errors, 2 of which are "type argument can't be inferred" errors, which I'm sure is causing the 3 error. So "films.OrderBy" is the first and "a.Releases.Select" is the second.

Comment: @KingKing, see my comment to my original question if that help. Thanks.

Comment: @HenryC I've not tested the query however I've just edited and tried copying and pasting into my code editor window and there is no syntax error now. You could try, it should work.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I changed my approach to this problem and resolved it based on the "normal" approaches out there, one of which was given as answer but subsequently deleted by the poster. What I ended up doing is moving my select down to the repository layer where I do have the DbContext and was able to do a "simple" left outer join style query like this...

```
var films = (from f in db.Films
             join r in db.Releases on f.Id equals r.FilmId into FR
             from a in FR.DefaultIfEmpty()
             join d in db.ReleaseDates on a.Id equals d.ReleaseId into RRD
             from b in RRD.DefaultIfEmpty()
             orderby b.Date ascending
             select f);
```

@KingKing, thanks for your answer, I think it may come in handy in some other places where we have these sort of aggregate fields based on properties of sub-collections or even properties of sub-sub-collections.